# How qt find <Qxxx/qxxx.h>?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, compilation

In Qt 6.4.0, we can use such code to include qt components:

```
#include <QtCore/qchar.h>
#include <QtCore/qbytearray.h>
#include <QtCore/qbytearrayview.h>
#include <QtWidgets/qtwidgetsglobal.h>
```

But I found that the real paths of those .h file are NOT under such folder like `QtCore`, `QtWidgets` etc. , actually most of them are under such directory:
`/Users/tony/Qt/6.4.0/macos/lib/QtXXX.framework/Headers/qtxxx.h`

I'm wondering that since `QtCore` is not the real path but `Headers`, Shouldn't we write `#include "Headers/qtxxx.h"` ? how can `#include <QtCore/qchar.h>` such path works?

Comment: Read about makefiles and include paths.

Comment: The documentation for e.g. [`QByteArray`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qbytearray.html) tells you which header to include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been solved: This phenomenon only shows on MacOS since MacOS uses "framework" to organize a set of lib and headers, which can be parsed by the clang-module name to the realpath.

Answer (score 0):

## Using the `-I` argument

You have to tell to your compiler which directory you want to include to find the headers properly. For example in clang and gcc you can use this directory as `-I` argument, like this:

```bash
clang++ yourprogram.cpp -I /Users/tony/Qt/6.4.0/macos/lib/QtXXX.framework/Headers/
```

And in your source code you will write includes at this way:

```cpp
#include "QtCore/qchar.h"
#include "QtCore/qbytearray.h"
#include "QtCore/qbytearrayview.h"
#include "QtWidgets/qtwidgetsglobal.h"
```

Note it uses `" "` instead `< >`, this means you are finding the included files relative to your compile options instead of your system.

Although this works, it's recommended to use relative paths of your project to point headers directories.

Comment: What I'm wondering is that since the folder `Headers` includes those header files instead of `QtCore` etc.,  why not writing `#include <Headers/qchar.h>` but `#include <QtCore/qchar.h>` ? The `QtCore` folder doesn't exist at all.

Comment: as you are including  QtCore library with "<>" the compiler are searching for system headers instead the directory you pointed out. I don't know much things about Mac, but in linux the system libraries are located in /usr/lib/ directory.